Font asset "CupertinoIcons.ttf" and "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 257628 to 1172 bytes (99.5% reduction)
I was working on a project, and when I do build, this error appears, and it remains like this in all the projects I have. When I use (--no-tree-shake-icons) as written, build does, but the site remains empty.enter image description here
I tried some solutions but to no avail
